# How to collapse multiple rows to one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with tabular data where every single one of my columns is Categorical except for two, I'll call them var_1 and var_2. Right now, I only display one value per row. I would like to remove this redundancy by combining rows so that I display var_1 and var_2 in one row instead of displaying them in two rows.

An example:

Currently, my dataframe looks like this:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   Cat_1    | Cat_2 | Cat_3 | Cat_4 | Var_1 | Var_2 | Cat_5 | Cat_6 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 28/01/2018 | A1    |       | Left  | 10.0  | NAN   | Yes   | Yes   |
| 28/01/2018 | A1    |       | Left  | NAN   | 150   | Yes   | Yes   |
| 29/01/2018 | A2    |       | Left  | 88.0  | NAN   | No    | Yes   |
| 29/01/2018 | A2    |       | Left  | NAN   | 100   | No    | Yes   |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to combine the rows where all the categorical variables are identical and display the values for Var_1 and Var_2 side by side like this.

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   Cat_1    | Cat_2 | Cat_3 | Cat_4 | Var_1 | Var_2 | Cat_5 | Cat_6 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 28/01/2018 | A1    |       | Left  | 10.0  |   150 | Yes   | Yes   |
| 29/01/2018 | A2    |       | Left  | 88.0  |   100 | No    | Yes   |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'm guaranteed that there is at most 2 rows which share identical everything. One of these rows will have NAN in Var_1 and a numerical value in Var_2 while the other row would have NAN in Var_2 and a numerical value in Var_1.

I tried playing around with `pd.grouby`, `pd.melt` and `pd.concat` but to no avail.

Comment: What did you do when you tried to groupby()?  How would you identify a unique case -- is it a combination of Cat_1 and Cat_2, or do the other categorical variables enter into it?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df.fillna(0).groupby(by=['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4','cat5','cat6']).agg('sum')
```

Comment: Can you post code to create your dataframe? I will work on finding what's going wrong here

Comment: I have similar problem. thanks for this solution. Will you be able to help with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71522999/how-to-collapse-near-duplicates-into-one-row-using-modified-bfill-pandas