# How to collapse near duplicates into one row using modified bfill pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, fillna

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
ID,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6
1,X,,X,,,X,A,B,C
1,X,,X,,,X,A,B,C
1,X,,X,,,X,A,B,C
2,X,,,X,,X,A,B,C,D,E
3,X,X,X,,,X,A
3,X,X,X,,,X,,B,,C
3,X,X,X,,,X,,D,C
4,X,X,,,,,A,B
4,,,,X,,X,G,H,I
4,,,X,,,,T

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to do the below

a) Remove full duplicates (where all values of each column match). **ex: ID=1 (keep=first)**

b) Collapse near duplicates into one row. **ex: ID= 3 and 4**. Near duplicates are rows where only ID match but rest of the `F numbered and L number columns differ`

I was trying the below but it results in incorrect output

The below code misses to copy other `L numbered values which doesn't have NA before`

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first') # this drops full duplicates ex:ID = 1
df.groupby(['ID'])['ID','F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6','L1','L2','L3','L4','L5','L6'].bfill().drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep='first')
```

In real data, there are 50 F columns and 50 L columns. For `F columns` the position of X is important and has to be correct whereas for L columns, it can be anywhere as long as it is captured, it is fine.

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#first omit all duplicates by all columns
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')

cL = df.filter(like='L').columns
cF = df.filter(like='F').columns

def f(x):
     s =  pd.Series(x.stack().unique()).rename(lambda x: f'L{x + 1}')
     print (s)
     return s

#recreate L columns by remove missing values and duplicates
#f = lambda x: pd.Series(x.stack().unique()).rename(lambda x: f'L{x + 1}')
df1 = df[cL].groupby(df['ID']).apply(f).unstack()

#remove original L columns
df = df.drop(cL, axis=1)
#for F columns processing with original solution
df[cF] = df.groupby(['ID'])[cF].bfill()
#after remove duplicates for F columns add L columns in df1
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep='first').join(df1, on='ID')
print (df)
   ID F1   F2   F3   F4  F5 F6 L1 L2 L3   L4   L5   L6
0   1  X  NaN    X  NaN NaN  X  A  B  C  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   2  X  NaN  NaN    X NaN  X  A  B  C    D    E  NaN
4   3  X    X    X  NaN NaN  X  A  B  C    D  NaN  NaN
7   4  X    X    X    X NaN  X  A  B  G    H    I    T
```

Comment: @TheGreat - Can you explian why is in `L4` value `H` ? This vaue is not in `L4`

Comment: We don't have to worry about positions for `L column values`. We just need to put everything in single row for each ID (if they have multiple rows). We need to worry about position only for `F column values`

Comment: @TheGreat - One question - whats happens if more non duplicated values like number of `L` columns? Then is possible add new column `L7` ?

Comment: Yes, you can add new column L7.

Comment: @TheGreat - OK, then my solution is like need.

Comment: @TheGreat - If orderinf is not important for L columns

Comment: okay, let me try and update you. Yes, order is not important for L columns (but F columns is important)

Comment: Can help me understand how this line works? `f = lambda x: pd.Series(x.stack().unique()).rename(lambda x: f'L{x + 1}')`? if you have time

Comment: @TheGreat - Sure, it get all L columns per ID and squeeze to Series - with remove NaNs and duplicates. And recreate L columns by number of values, so possible `L7` if more values like original columns names. So finnaly get `df1` with unique `ID` and columns with all non duplicated values.

Comment: Is it possible to write the above statement without lambda but by using for loop or whatever (just for my understanding). solution is perfect okay. So, I can try line by line to learn it works.

Comment: @TheGreat - I rewrite solution for def function, there is `print` for see how it working

Comment: just a thank you note. I am amazed by the speed and skill that you have in solving python pandas problems

Comment: @TheGreat - today it was slow ;) I think because Friday ;)

Comment: Hi, in the above code, if I write at the start `df.drop_duplicates(keep=first)`, then at the end, I can just write `df.join(df1, on='ID')`. Am I right? You are removing the full duplicates at the last (which I did in first step in my code).

Comment: @TheGreat - yop, it is good idea.

Comment: @TheGreat - Added to answer. It is good use it first.

Comment: Is this something that you would be able to help me with?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526079/pandas-write-output-to-a-specific-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file